# How to combine multiple dtype 'objects' into a single variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Ok I edited this to (hopefully) simplify the problem. I have 2 variables and they each have the following output:

```
var1: Index(['B4_1', 'B4_2','B4_3', 'B4_4'],
      dtype='object', length=4)
```

```
var2: Index(['B1_1', 'B1_2','B1_3', 'B1_4'],
      dtype='object', length=4)
```

I am trying to combine them into one variable `var` that looks like this (order does not matter):

```
Index(['B4_1', 'B4_2','B4_3', 'B4_4','B1_1', 'B1_2','B1_3', 'B1_4'],
      dtype='object', length=8)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

For more context to the problem:

Each of these strings (i.e. `'B1_1'`) is the row index of a dataframe and each corresponds to an x,y coordinate in that dataframe. I am trying to plot all of the coordinates that correspond to these strings in one scatter plot. The dataframe looks like this:

```
       'x'    'y'
B1_1   0   |   1
B2_1   1   |   5
B3_1   8   |  -2
B4_1   0   |   0 
...   ...  |  ... 
B1_4   16  |   0
B2_4   10  |  -5
B3_4   0   |   9
B4_4   8   |  -2
```

I am trying to plot all of the points that correspond to the B1 and B4 samples,  so I do not want to plot every coordinate pair in the dataframe.

For a single sample I can plot as such:

```
    var1 = df.index[df.index.str.contains('B4')]
    ax.scatter(df.loc[var1, 'x'], df.loc[var1, 'y'])
```

How do I do this for both B1 and B4 together?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. _The coordinates are indexed using these variables as substrings. So for example one coordinate I might want could be indexed by `'b1_12345'`._ Why?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can use `Index.union` to combine 2 index objects.
so in this case:
if `var` and `var2` are both Index objects:

```
var = var.union(var2)
```

will combine into one index object by taking the union.